# Ошибка в работе триггера. Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, триггер

Имеется две таблицы: товары (shop) и продажи (sale). В таблице товара есть цена. В таблице продаж есть id товара, количество проданного товара и прибыль. Я попытался написать триггер, который при изменении или добавлении записей в таблицу sale рассчитывает прибыль.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upd_proceeds() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $upd_proceeds$
DECLARE
    proc money;
BEGIN
    proc = NEW.quantity * (SELECT price FROM shop WHERE NEW.product_id = shop.id);
--  RAISE EXCEPTION '%', proc;
    UPDATE sale SET proceeds = proc;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$upd_proceeds$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER t_sale
AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON sale FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE upd_proceeds ();
```

Опытным путем я выяснил, что все ломается со строки с UPDATE. Легче от этого не стало.
В сообщениях СУБД:

```
ОШИБКА:  превышен предел глубины стека
HINT:  Увеличьте параметр конфигурации "max_stack_depth" (текущее значение 2048 КБ), предварительно убедившись, что ОС предоставляет достаточный размер стека.
CONTEXT:  SQL-оператор: "SELECT NEW.quantity * (SELECT price FROM shop WHERE NEW.product_id = shop.id)"
функция PL/pgSQL upd_proceeds(), строка 5, оператор присваивание
SQL-оператор: "UPDATE sale SET proceeds = proc"
функция PL/pgSQL upd_proceeds(), строка 7, оператор SQL-оператор
SQL-оператор: "UPDATE sale SET proceeds = proc"
функция PL/pgSQL upd_proceeds(), строка 7, оператор SQL-оператор
```

...и так еще миллион раз.
Мне со стороны задача показалась легкой, но уже часа два голову ломаю, не могу найти решение.

Comment: 1) Триггер должен обновить записываемое значение (которое лежит в `NEW.proceeds`) - оператором `SET`, а не запросом; 2) Триггер должен сделать это до записи данных, т.е. `BEFORE UPDATE`.

Comment: у вас триггер after update. В триггере вы делаете безусловное обновление всех строк этой же самой таблицы. Вы думаете есть причина почему это не будет порождать бесконечную рекурсию?